# Evaluate improper integrals

Tags: integration, limits, improper-integrals

I can't get an answer for these two questions... help?

1. $ \int_{-2}^0 \frac{x^2}{\left(1+x^3\right) ^2} dx $
2. $ \int_{0}^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^\frac13} dx$

For question 1 I tried integrating but it gets more and more complicated. I got until $ \int \frac{1}{6(1+x^3} \frac{6x^2(1+x^3}{(1+x^3)^2}$ I'm not sure what to do afterwards or if it is even correct.
For question 2 I got until here. $$\begin{eqnarray} \int_{0}^1 \ln x \cdot x^\frac{-1}{3} &=& \ln x\cdot\frac32x^\frac23-\int_0^1\frac32x^\frac{-1}{3}\cr&=&\left[\frac32 x^\frac23 \cdot\left(\ln x - \frac32 \right)\right]_0^1\\&=&-\frac94-(???) \end{eqnarray} $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question 1:**

Notice $(1+x^3)' = 3x^2$, thus you are integrating "almost" $\frac{u'}{u^2}$, whose primitive is $-\frac{1}{u}$.

**However**, $1+x^3=0$ for $x=-1$, and your function $x\to\frac{x^2}{(1+x^3)^2}$ is not integrable on $[-2,0]$. It has a primitive, easy to compute with the hint above, but not defined at $x=-1$, and you can't integrate on an interval containing $-1$.

**Question 2:**

Try change of variable $x=y^3$, thus $\mathrm{d}x=3y^2\mathrm{d}y$ and

$$ \int \frac{\ln x}{x^\frac13} \mathrm{d}x = \int \frac{\log (y^3)}{y}3y^2\mathrm{d}y=
9\int y\log (y)\mathrm{d}y$$

And you can easily integrate this by parts.

The function $x\to\frac{\log x}{x^{1/3}}$ is like above not defined for $x=0$, but unlike the function in question 1, this function is integrable at $x=0$, and continuous on $]0,1]$, thus the integral exists, and the hint above to compute its primitive will do the job.

---

Just a remark on vocabulary: primitive is the same as antiderivative or indefinite integral, look for example on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative).

Comment: i still don't get what you mean for question 1?? isn't the differentiation 3x^2 not 2x^2?? what you mean by primitive???

Comment: Yes, a silly mistake, thanks ;-) And a second silly mistake: while the primitive (or indefinite integral if you prefer) is easy to compute, the function is certainly not integrable on $[-2, 0]$ !!! I missed this.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
The first one is trivial.

$\large\tt Second\ one$:
With $\mu > -1$:

\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{1/3}}\,\dd x}&=
\lim_{\mu \to -1/3}\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\mu}\,\dd x
=\lim_{\mu \to -1/3}\partiald{}{\mu}\pars{1 \over \mu + 1}
=\lim_{\mu \to -1/3}\bracks{-\,{1 \over \pars{\mu + 1}^{2}}}
\\[3mm]&=-\,{1 \over \pars{-1/3 + 1}^{2}} = \color{#00f}{\large -\,{9 \over 4}}
\end{align}